# HttpContext.Current vs System.Web.UI.Page.Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Is there any difference between `HttpContext.Current` and `System.Web.UI.Page.Context`? Is there a difference between then `HttpContext` parameter at the `ProcesRequest` method of an `IHttpHandler`?

If there is no difference, why not always use `HttpContext.Current`?

Are there situations where it is better not to use `HttpContext.Current`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have choice it is always better to avoid using global variables/properties of any kind in favor of more local versions to make code more self-documenting (explicit dependencies are easier to see) and testable (it is easier to pass mock/custom object than trying to set up potentially non-writable global property).

In case of `HttpRequest` all ways you've mentioned will give you the same object. The difference is if you pass one in to your methods than you can test code much easier compared to using `HttpContext.Current`.